# There is no implicit conversion between null and null

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have this weird piece of code (that will never, ever be used in production code) that produces a weird compilation error and I'd want to know more about this behavior,

```
string MyMethod(string s)
{
   return s == null ? null : null;
}
```

The error I get is:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `null` and `null`

What explains this behavior?

Comment: Because your method is not nullable a returned method cannot be null Nullable<string> MyMethod(string? s)

Comment: return t == null ? (string)null : null;

Comment: You can't create a `Nullable<String>` since String is already nullable

Comment: @user3842306: `string` is a reference type, so yes, `null` is a perfectly valid return value.  That is not the issue, the problem is with ternary type deduction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What explains this behavior?

The C# 5 specification, section 7.14:

> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator control the type of the conditional expression.
>
> - If x has type X and y has type Y then [...]
> - If only one of x and y has a type, and both x and y, of are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Your situation is the last of these options - the expression `null` has no type, therefore neither `x` and `y` have a type, therefore you get a compile-time error.

The fact that you're trying to use the *result* of the conditional operator expression has no bearing on the type of the expression - the compiler works from the "inside out" as it were - it finds the type of the expression and then checks that your usage of it is correct.

In this case, there *is* no type, therefore compilation fails.

In C# 1, there was a "null type" which was regarded as the type of the `null` literal - but that concept was removed in the C# 3 specification. (There was no full C# 2 specification from MS; it was merely a set of additions to the C# 2 specification.)

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator needs to determine the type of its result based on the type of the second and third operands.  `null` has no type, and so the conditional operator can't figure out what type its value will resolve to.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the compiler is getting confused, because it can't determine what type is being returned. Based only on the information that it's `null`, it could be any reference type at all.

To fix it, cast one or both of your `null`s to be `(string)null` and it should understand.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the result of the conditional operator cannot be infered from neither of the options, since neither specifies a type or inferes one. Solution can be to case either to string:

```
string MyMethod(string s)
{
   return s == null ? (string)null : null;
}
```

OF course, no need for this condition either, as it always returns null, instead it can be:

```
string MyMethod(string s)
{
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I knew the condition was useless, I just happened to type this and had an error, I got curious and couldn't find the answer